# Rewrite rules in Boomla

Tags: boomla

Is it possible to create something like rewrite rules in Boomla? For example, configure that a URL

```
//example.com/search-result/asdf
```

be handled by a given app, whether or not a file with this URL exists. I.e. to treat this URL as if it was something like

```
//example.com/search-result?q=asdf
```

If not, is it planned?

Comment: I guess this question is close to equivalent with: can I create custom 404 error pages?

Answer (score 0):

Planned but not possible right now (2017-05-15).

As planned, you will not be able to have custom rewrite rules that takes precedent over the filesystem. There will be some kind of a .RequestNotFound interface or similar for specifying such behavior. The event will bubble up along the filesystem tree and the first file to implement the interface will handle it.

Comment: Bernát: Are you just curious or is this an urgent requirement for you?

Comment: Ok, this sounds perfect.
I have a nice idea and this would make it even nicer, but nothing serious or urgent right now.

Comment: @Bernát - ok, thx for the feedback. In case it would be not implemented at a time you really need it, let me know as it it not a complex feature, there are just others that are pressing issues.